# SQL Server REPLACE Characters in Different Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, cursor

I am trying to figure out how to replace characters in one table using characters from columns in another table in SQL Server. I think the best way to do this is using a cursor and run the REPLACE statement but I am unsure exactly how the syntax would look like. I have many rows in each table so I would like to be able to run this once and have it loop through   table1 and replace any values that should be replaced using the data in table2. I've posted an example below of what I want my code to do.

table1 (contains myString column):

```
           myString

   your favorite color is blue
   his favorite color is red
   their favorite color is green
```

table2 (contains origChar and replaceChar columns):

```
        origChar    replaceChar
          blue         red
          your         my
          green        red
          their        our
```

table1 Result after REPLACE:

```
       myString

    my favorite color is red
    his favorite color is red
    our favorite color is red
```

Here are some samples of my work so far. Any thoughts of how to get any of these methods to work as intended.

sample one:

```
              DECLARE @cRowID INT;
              DECLARE @cOrigChar VARCHAR(50);
              DECLARE @cReplaceChar VARCHAR(50);
              DECLARE @cMyString VARCHAR(50);

              DECLARE @mapCursor as CURSOR;

              SET @mapCursor = CURSOR FOR
              SELECT [RowID]
                    ,[myString]
              FROM [dbo].[table1]; 

              OPEN @mapCursor;
              FETCH NEXT FROM @mapCursor INTO @cRowID,
                                              @cOrigChar,
                                              @cReplaceChar,
                                              @cMyString;

                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                BEGIN

                  UPDATE [dbo].[table1]
                  SET myString = REPLACE(myString, origChar, replaceChar)
                  WHERE origChar <> replaceChar

                END

                CLOSE @mapCursor;
                DEALLOCATE @mapCursor;
```

sample two:

```
            DECLARE @RowID INT = 0

            WHILE (1 = 1) 
            BEGIN  

              SELECT @RowID = RowID
              FROM [dbo].[table1]
              WHERE RowID > @RowID 
              ORDER BY RowID

              IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BREAK;

                  UPDATE .[dbo].[table1]
                  SET myString = REPLACE(myString, origChar, replaceChar)
                  WHERE origChar <> replaceChar


              SELECT TOP 1000 [myString]
              FROM [dbo].[table1]



            END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a better way to do this than in a cursor, but to help you with your cursor approach, it probably makes more sense to loop over the pairs of original/replacement values rather than looping over every string value. You'll only need two variables, the orig/replace, and while you `DECLARE` a cursor, it's not referenced with a `@`.  Also, you need to add a `FETCH` inside your `WHILE` loop in order to progress through the value pairs, (missing this results in infinite loop):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @origChar varchar(MAX)
       ,@replaceChar varchar(MAX)
DECLARE xyz CURSOR
FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT origChar,replaceChar
    FROM Table2
OPEN xyz 
FETCH NEXT FROM xyz 
INTO @origChar,@replaceChar 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

UPDATE Table1
SET myString = REPLACE(myString,@origChar,@replaceChar)

    FETCH NEXT FROM xyz 
    INTO @origChar,@replaceChar  
END
CLOSE xyz 
DEALLOCATE xyz 
GO
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b07ae/2/0)

Comment: When I run this I get stuck in an infinite loop and when I select myString I see that some values change while others don't. Why is this happening. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I appears to work perfectly. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.